# Select OSM admin boundary which links with pelias geocoder result

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, geocoding

We use pelias geocoder environment in our project. There is a case "selection a polygon, which links with pelias result." For example we choose "Muenich" in search field -> on client we see this:

[image: polygon]

How to realise it? Geocoder answers have only bbox and node coordinate (if i use `&source=osm` too), how to links them with osm admin boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[answer has been removed by original poster]